# ImportError: DLL load failed: El sistema operativo no puede ejecutar %1

Tags: python, dll, cryptography

I am trying to connect using netmiko library to a cisco switch and I get the mentioned error. Logging paramiko messages I get the next error:
paramiko.transport:     from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib
ERR [20181119-11:16:34.572] thr=1   paramiko.transport: ImportError: DLL load failed: El sistema operativo no puede ejecutar %1.
El sistema operativo no puede ejecutar %1-> The operative system cannot execute %1

My python -v command shows this:
Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, May  1 2018, 18:37:09) [MSC v.1500 64 b
it (AMD64)] on win32

Any idea of the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The soltuion was unistalling the anaconda software and after that netmiko works without problems.